# Listing contents of a list containing class objects not working properly

Tags: python, list, class, methods

I have a class `task` that contains information of a task and a method to expand it as follows:

```
#define class for tasks
class task:
    def __init__(self, name, date, category):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.category = category
    def expand(self): # returns the contents of the task
        print(str(self.name) + " is due " + str(self.date))
```

and a function `listTasks()` that lists the contents of a standard list that contains objects of the class task as follows:

```
def listTasks():
    i = 1
    for task in data:
        print("%s. %s" % (i, task.expand()))
        i = i+1
```

The idea is for the `listTasks` function to display a coherent list that looks like

```
1. Foo is due tomorrow
2. Foobar is due in 2 days
3. FooFoo is due in five years
```

etc.. but the actual output looks as follows:

```
foo is due tomorrow
1. None
foobar is due in 2 days
2. None
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `expand()` is just `print`ing the result and not `return`ing it. So inside the loop it is being called and printing the line, but returning `None` and then the print from the loop becomes `i. None`.

Change the function to:

```py
def expand(self): # returns the contents of the task
    return str(self.name) + " is due " + str(self.date)
```

To make it more readable I would also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for the loop, like so:

```py
def listTasks():
    for i, task in enumerate(data, 1):
        print("%s. %s" % (i, task.expand()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue as @Tomerikoo pointed out is that you're not *returning* rather *printing* the string in your `expand` method.

However I wanted to point out a couple more possible improvements to your code:

- Class names should be CamelCase, and functions should be lower_case_separated_with_underscores according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).
- <del>`__repr__`</del> [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) is a the built-in method to compute the "official" string representation of an object
- [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) make your code more readable
- you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to iterate through a list with a counter

```py
from datetime import datetime


class Task:
    def __init__(self, name, date, category):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.category = category

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is due {self.date}" # you need to return the information


data = [Task("test", datetime.now(), "something"), Task("test2", datetime.now(), "something")]


def list_tasks():
    for i, task in enumerate(data, 1):
        print(f"{i}. {task}")


list_tasks()
```

Comment: That's not the recommended use of `__repr__`. Maybe you meant `__str__`. the function `__repr__` is meant to be more like: `f"Task({self.name}, {self.date}, {self.category})"`. A valid python expression. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#object.__repr__)